# how does careers.stackoverflow.com find my stackoverflow id?

Tags: discussion, jobs, openid, linked-accounts

if I go to careers.stackoverflow.com and type in the same openId I use to login to stackoverflow then how does it find my stackoverflow id?

do they save data on an id and associate it that way? or can any other third party (any other site) do that as well?

Comment: Belongs on Meta.

Answer (score 1):

Careers.stackoverflow and stackoverflow are operated by the same company, so it stands to reason they do a simple internal lookup.

<strike>On the other hand, using the openID it would in theory be possible to a third party to make the association as well - if not legally through an API, then through scraping of the accounts pages.</strike>

Comment: Your openID is only visible in your own public profile page.  You can't see others' openids, and so you couldn't get them via scraping.

Comment: Cheers @Joel, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

By magic...

...or OpenID (according to the page itself).

> You can opt to associate your Stack Overflow account with your CV, and it will appear on both your public and private CV views.
>
> All account matching is by OpenID. For best results, please sign in to careers with the same OpenID that you use on Stack Overflow.

How this exactly works, I am not 100% sure as I remember someone here saying that there is a problem with Google assigning unique IDs with every login - I am guessing that they either found a workaround or Google no longer does this... however, I am no expert and really can't comment here.